# Google Drive API (v3) --- Download file as a service

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

hope this question makes sense: Is there a way I can download files from a drive without reiterating the service account every time? So for example, I have a program that allows me to backup my Gapps organization drives. The program currently works like this:

1. Logs in to each account with the service I created in the Google developer console
2. Checks the token as a source for changed files from the last time the backup ran to the current execution
3. IF the token is different, executes a file list request and records the fileId and actual fileName for the files changed, then puts both values into a temporary text document as 2 columns `("fileId,fileName")`. Here is what I'm using for the file resource list

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Changes detected. Making notes while we go through these.");
   if (File.Exists(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok"))
       File.Delete(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok");

   using (StreamWriter deltalog = new StreamWriter(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok", true))
   {
       while (pageToken != null)
       {
           counter1++;
           var request = CreateService.BuildService(user).Changes.List(pageToken);

           //StreamWriter deltalog = new StreamWriter(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok", true);
           request.Fields = "*";
           request.Spaces = "drive";

           var changes = request.Execute();
           foreach (var change in changes.Changes)
           {
               try
               {
                   string updatedfile = change.File.Name;
                   //string updatedfile = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Get(change.FileId).Execute().Name;
                   // Record the changed file
                   Console.WriteLine(user + ": New or changed file found: " + updatedfile + "\n");
                   logFile.WriteLine(user + ": New or changed file found: " + change.FileId + " --- " + updatedfile);
                   deltalog.Write(change.FileId + "," + updatedfile+"\n");
                   deltalog.Flush();
               }
   ```
4. Start exporting the files out as documents to my server for backup. To do this, I log into the Gapps domain with my service account 3 different times for one file for each user. Right now, I'm reading the file created from step 3 and splitting the values so that I have the fileId and Filename on hand. The code looks like this:

   ```
   FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.List();
   listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
   listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
   string[] deltafiles = File.ReadAllLines(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok");


   IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
       .Files;

   Console.WriteLine("\nFiles to backup:\n");
   if (deltafiles == null)
   {
       return;
   }
   else
   { 

       foreach (var file in deltafiles)
       {
           try
           {
               // Our file is a CSV. Column 1 = file ID, Column 2 = File name
               var values = file.Split(',');
               string fileId = values[0];
               string fileName = values[1];

               fileName = fileName.Replace('\\', '_').Replace('/', '_').Replace(':', '_').Replace('!', '_').Replace('\'', '_').Replace('*', '_');

               Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + values[1]);
               logFile.WriteLine("ID: " + values[0] + " - Filename: " + values[1]);
               var requestfileid = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Get(fileId);
               var getfile = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
               var request = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Export(fileId, getfile.MimeType);
   ```

and so forth.

If I try to change the requestfileid to values[0] (which would be the fileId for that file in the loop), then the MediaDownloader doesn't work because it's no longer part of the Files.Get constructor.

Is there anything I can do, or overlooking, so that the service account only has to log in once to do everything it needs per account?

Hope that gibberish makes sense.

I've been using https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet and the API documentation as my source for information, and I got everything working the way I want it to, Except for having to log in as the service multiple times for One file. Any help or point in the right direction would sure be appreciated.  Thank you!